# Android listview with check boxes?

Tags: android, listview

I am developing an application which uses list view with check-boxes,consider there are `10 items` on `list-view` items,And by default in that check boxes are checked,Until now every thing is working fine for me here is my problem,When I **uncheck any check-box** in list-view **whole list-view need to be refresh**.

Comment: And where is your code? Can you share with us?

Comment: Do you mean after one check box is unchecked, all checkboxes will be unchecked?

Comment: sry, if any one of the check box is unchecked means whole data in the listview should be refreshed,means again the checkbox which is un checked should be  checked..

Comment: Your question is not so clear.Post ur code here or explain with images what u want to do....

Comment: one samll help how i can get the position of check boxes in listview android

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Nikhil just keep in mind that **defining a custom adapter is one time practice**, once you define and understand it properly then you can customize any views like ListView, GridView, Gallery, Spinner. So go through the below answer properly.

For defining ListView with CheckBox (or any View), you have to define your own custom adapter. For defining custom adapter, follow below steps:

1. Define a custom row file (which represents every items of your listview)
2. Define a adapter class and extends BaseAdapter.
3. Inflate the above row xml file inside the getView() method of this adapter class.

In your case,

### 1st step: (Define row xml file)

```
<RelativeLayout>
   <TextView>
   <CheckBox>
</RelativeLayout>
```

### 2nd & 3rd step: (Define custom adapter class)

```
public class MyListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
  ....
  ....


   static class ViewHolder {
        protected TextView text;
        protected CheckBox checkbox;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
            view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.rowbuttonlayout, null);
            final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label);
            viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check);
            viewHolder.checkbox
                    .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                boolean isChecked) {
                            Model element = (Model) viewHolder.checkbox
                                    .getTag();
                            element.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());

                        }
                    });
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
            viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
        } else {
            view = convertView;
            ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
        }
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        holder.text.setText(list.get(position).getName());
        holder.checkbox.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());


.......
.......
}
```

Comment: Can u plz define this Model Class in this answer

Comment: what is list in list.get(position) ?

Answer (score -1):

checkbox of a particular item have no info. about listView so to get its positiion , set id as position dthen get id in click listener .

second way is check/uncheck on listItemClick by set  a ListItemClickListener instead of checkListener on checkBox , this is useful only when list item have just one clickable item  , which is your checkbox .

Comment: Well First way is self explanatory and second is exactly what above ans. of paresh says .