# Toggle checkbox programmatically

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a ListView of items that need to be checkable/uncheckable.  I have set up an ArrayAdapter that is currently using android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice as the row, and everything displays just fine.  I am also able to properly get the clicks on this item.  However, the Checkbox in the UI *does not toggle* when the item is selected.  I've been trying to figure this out for a while, can anyone point me in the right direction?  I just want to know how to force the UI to update to reflect the changed state of the checkbox.

I can provide code if needed, but I'm trying to look for something very specific here, so I figure posting a bunch of my code wouldn't be of much help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

First of all go through my this answer: [Android listview with check boxes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8060514/android-listview-with-check-boxes/8060732#8060732)

Nice as you want to implement checked/unchecked check boxes in ListView, you just need to implement below lines in getView() method:

```
 // also check this lines in the above example
ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
holder.checkbox.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());
```

Also check the getView() method for the implementation of event on CheckBox residing inside the ListView:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
        view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.rowbuttonlayout, null);
        final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label);
        viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check);
        viewHolder.checkbox
            .setOnCheckedChangeListener(
                new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                        boolean isChecked) {
                    Model element = (Model) viewHolder.checkbox
                            .getTag();
                    element.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());
                }
            });
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
        viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
    } else {
        view = convertView;
        ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
    }
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    holder.text.setText(list.get(position).getName());
    holder.checkbox.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());
    // ......  
}
```

Comment: +1 i am your follower,can you please tell me what to do (read/watch) to know more about android as you do.! thanks..learnt a lot from your answers.

Comment: Thanx for the kind words. I am always trying to learn a topic for a day and doing SO and my blog. what else require to learn new topic :) , Where are you from?

Comment: India, I also do the thing come to SO and find atleast one topic i dont know and get the question and answer about that..but still sometime i got bored/tired of doing that..but you guys keep encouraging me.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  So you're saying neither the base ListView class nor the base ArrayAdapter will work for the purpose of getting checkboxes to work?

Comment: ArrayAdapter can also work, check this example http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: @PareshMayani do you have any idea how to make this to work with single checkbox selection ? I tried everything and it doesn't seem to work. The closest I got was to manually clear all the selection states from the custom items, but it only worked for the rows above my selection, the ones bellow required a second click to work.

Answer (score 36):

Programmatically in java code

```
CheckBox mCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

mCheckBox.setChecked(true); //to check
mCheckBox.setChecked(false); //to uncheck
```

In android XML

```
android:checked="true" //to check
android:checked="false" //to uncheck
```

as

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="true"
    android:text="Checkbox Item" />
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried the following?

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id) {

    //Invert the checkbox-status        
    ((CheckedTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text1)).setChecked(!isChecked());

    return;

}
```

Comment: The items in the list are dynamic--there's no unique XML ID for every row item.  Unless I've got my understanding of that wrong?  But I tried it anyway, and got a NullPointerException :(

Comment: In any case, you don't need to do that, you can do `checkbox.toggle()` ;)

Answer (score 2):

In kotlin, set the checkbox unchecked programmatically

```
binding.imageCheckBox.post { binding.imageCheckBox.setChecked(false) }
```

and set the checkbox checked programmatically

```
binding.imageCheckBox.post { binding.imageCheckBox.setChecked(true) }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need, it helped me out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom base adapter. This will allow you to choose only one at at time, but you may change this by undoing the check to see which ones are selected.

```
public class CheckBoxGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList<Holder> list;
    int res;
    Context context;

    public CheckBoxGridAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Holder> list, int layoutResourceId) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.context = context;
        this.list =list;
        this.res = layoutResourceId;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
        final ViewHolder holder; 
        if (convertView == null) { 
            convertView = inflater.inflate(res, 
                    parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder(); 
            holder.tv1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxTxt); 
            holder.cb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox); 
           convertView.setTag(holder); 
       } else { 
           holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(); 
       } 
       Holder h = list.get(position);
       holder.tv1.setText(h.getCBName());
       holder.cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

           @Override
           public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                   boolean isChecked) {
               if(isChecked)
               {
                    int pos = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();
                    checkChecks(pos);               
               }
               CheckBoxGridAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
           }
       });
       holder.cb.setTag(position);
       holder.cb.setChecked(list.get(position).getSelectState());
       return convertView; 
    }

    protected void checkChecks(int pos) {
            for(int i = 0;i<list.size();i++)
            {
                Holder h = (Holder) list.get(i);
                if(i==pos)
                {
                  Log.d( pos +" checked","is checked");
                  h.setSelectState(true);
                }
                else
                {
                     Log.d( i +" checked","is  not checked");
                     h.setSelectState(false);
                }
            }
    }

    static class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView tv1;
        CheckBox cb;
        RadioButton rb;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle the checkbox by doing this:

```
checkbox.setChecked(!checkbox.isChecked());
```

Where checkbox is your "Checkbox" element.