# How to set checkbox in arrayList checked with certain condition?

Tags: java, android, checkbox, arraylist

I have an arrayList in Custom Adapter, consisting of some strings and checkbox. and i want to set checkbox checked automatically with certain condition, but how to set the code so the checkbox checked automatically.

```
public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
    activity = a;
    data = d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View vi = convertView;

    if(convertView == null) 
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

    TextView no = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.txt_no);
    TextView code = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.txt_code);
    TextView name = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.txt_asset);
    TextView dept = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.txt_dept);
    CheckBox status = (CheckBox)vi.findViewById(R.id.cb_stat);

    HashMap<String, String> asset = new HashMap<String, String>();
    asset = data.get(position); 
    //Setting all values in listview
    no.setText(asset.get(ListLocationActivity.KEY_NO));
    code.setText(asset.get(ListLocationActivity.KEY_CODE));
    name.setText(asset.get(ListLocationActivity.KEY_NAME));
    dept.setText(asset.get(ListLocationActivity.KEY_DEPT));
    return vi;
}
```

This is my condition when i get the result, i want set checked the checkbox which the result suitable with the code in arraylist

```
for (int i = 0; i < assetList.size(); i++) {
            if (assetList.get(i).get(KEY_CODE).equals(scanAsset)){
                //set checked in certain list asset
               //(Here i confused how i can set the checkbox in list suitable with the code asset)
                Log.i("Asset code is ", scanAsset);
            }
        }
```

this code is work fine without set value in checkbox, Anyone can help me to solve this case, please . . . .
Thank you before

Comment: you're trying to just do `status.setChecked(true)`?

Comment: @Eluvatar i can't just do status.setChecked(true) if i do that all of the checkbox in array list will be checked. i need just suitable with my result and code in my list will be checked.

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8061374/3134811)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, where is the result coming from? you should be setting checked in `getView` then just call notifyDataSetChanged on the adapter to rebuild after you've changed the condition that causes `setChecked` to be true in `getView`

Comment: @eluvatar hmm i'm using scan barcode to get the result, so i don't show the code, sorry. the result i mean in 'scanAsset'. i don't want click the checkbox to set checked, but i want the checkbox set checked automatically when the result and contents in my code same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using actual objects instead of a HashMap but that's outside the scope of this question

I'd adjust your `getView` call to add this line before returning

```
status.setChecked(asset.containsKey(ListLocationActivity.KEY_CHECKED));
```

obviously create a new static key for checked, not sure where that's defined

then once get your scan result you referenced this above so I'll modify it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < assetList.size(); i++) {
    HashMap<String, String> asset = assetList.get(i);
    if (asset.get(KEY_CODE).equals(scanAsset)){
        asset.put(KEY_CHECKED, "Checked");
        Log.i("Asset code is ", scanAsset);
    }
}
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

so what we did is we created a new property for your adapter to key off, then if the asset you're currently building a view for in the adapter has that key then we want to check the check box, otherwise we want to not check it.

Comment: Wow it is work. Thank you very much it's solve my case, thanks again eluvatar. You're the best.

Comment: Glad I could help, just a note because you're new to SO, usually when you mark a question as answered you also up-vote it with the up arrow near the green check.

Comment: yes i'm new on SO, i want vote up your answer but, i still don't have enough rep to vote-up. so i still can't vote up your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Create a model object (here called AssetsWrapper) and set a boolean inside it.

```
// Model wrapper class
class AssetsWrapper {
    HashMap<String, String> mAssets;
    boolean mBoolean;
}


// Your code that checks the CheckBox
for (int i = 0; i < assetList.size(); i++) {
    if (assetList.get(i).get(KEY_CODE).equals(scanAsset)){
        assetList.get(i).mBoolean = true;
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

// YOUR ADAPTER CODE --------------------------------------------

// Constructor (notice that the ArrayList has changed)
public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<AssetsWrapper> d) {
    activity = a;
    data = d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}


public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // ...

    CheckBox status = (CheckBox)vi.findViewById(R.id.cb_stat);

    AssetsWrapper aw = getItem(position);

    // Here, the adapter reads the value from the model object.
    status.setChecked(aw.mBoolean);

    // ...

    return vi;
}
```