# Initializing views from within a for loop

Tags: java, android, android-xml

In my XML I have around 136 check boxes, I dont want to undergo the pain of initializing each one of them individually in the corresponding java file, I came up with a novel idea of doing this using a for loop, however android wont let me do it. I tried the code in the onCreate method. Do I need to declare something global? I dont know this might be a silly question though!

Following is my code:

```
       CheckBox[] C = new CheckBox[136];
            for(int i=1;i<=136;i++){
               C[i] = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox[i]);
            }
```

I want to know if this is valid or not and the reason behind.

Error: 
Type mismatch: cannot convert from CheckBox to CheckBox[]

checkBox cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: Have you tried using an ArrayList instead of array?

Comment: @mmnumbp I dont get it, sorry. How am I supposed to do it then? I mean the way you suggest will not yield in this situation.

Comment: I will try an arraylist @MarkM

Comment: use a listview with a custom layout inflated . You can have check box for each row.

Comment: user3 if you're trying to fill up an array, you have to instantiate it outside of the loop. so first you do `CheckBox[] c = new CheckBox[size];`, then inside the loop you add checkboxes to the array by doing `c[i] = (CheckBox) etc etc`

Comment: I tried that but the error is persistent.

Comment: What is `checkBox[i]` in `findViewById(R.id.checkBox[i])`? Is it an array of ID, for example `R.id.checkbox1`? Or maybe an array of the name of an ID, for example `"checkbox1"`?

Comment: Yes I tried to declare it as an int array, which is an array of ID. The views declared in XML. I am utterly confused now..

Comment: If it is an int array, then what you need to do is : **Remove** `R.id.` and change it to `findViewById(checkBox[i]);`

Comment: your loop will always cause an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, it should be `for(int i=0;i<136;i++)` instead

Comment: Aprian Its working now, type that in the answer box and Ill accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here is the working version

```
CheckBox[] C = new CheckBox[136];
// see thepoosh comment, you need to change to this:
for (int i = 0; i < 136; i++) {
   C[i] = (CheckBox) findViewById(checkBox[i]);
}
```

I don't know why you are getting Type Mismatch. But there will not be any array in `R.java`.

Comment: Just a Minor Edit:  **int[] checkBox = new int[136];

  for (int i = 0; i < 136; i++) {
   checkBox[i] = i;
  }**

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with your XML layout, but you probably don't want 136 checkboxes in there. Instead, you should use a `ListView`. Check out this example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8060514/android-listview-with-check-boxes).

The error you got was because that assignment was syntactically invalid. You needed to declare your array beforehand. When you actually assign the value, you don't need to specify the class again. For example:

```
CheckBox[] checkBoxes = new CheckBox[136];
...
checkBoxes[i] = //Whatever you want to assign this.
```

Comment: I would have used a listview, but that is not feasible in my scenario, However I get your logic and I implemented the same, however I still get an error. The same which I had categorized in my question.

Comment: Which error are you getting? You shouldn't be getting the `TypeMismatch` error anymore, assuming you implemented what's shown above.

Comment: I am getting the checkBox cannot be resolved or is not a field at  ***(R.id.checkBox[i])***