# Struct with getting the selected checkbox text from listview in android?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-checkbox

I am using arraylist and displaying the values in listview,now i want the selected text .I tried but i am not able to complete it .this is my code ,I want the selected text to store in arraylist.

```
public class EcConferenceNumber extends Activity{
    ListView checkBoxNumberListView;
    ConferenceAdapter adapter;
    Button doneBtn,cancelBtn;
    EditText profileName;
    CheckBoxListViewAdapter cbAdapter;
    static ArrayList<String> checkBoxData = null;
    String[]  myStrings;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ec_number_selection);    
        adapter = new ConferenceAdapter(this);
        checkBoxNumberListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.numberselectionlistView);

        doneBtn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.donenumberbutton);
        cancelBtn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.cancelnumberbutton);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        myStrings = intent.getStringArrayExtra("strings");

         checkBoxData=new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(myStrings));


          final CheckBoxListViewAdapter checkBoxListViewAdapter = new CheckBoxListViewAdapter(
                    EcConferenceNumber.this, adapter, checkBoxData);
                    checkBoxListViewAdapter.setSelectedString(new ArrayList<String>());
                    checkBoxNumberListView.setAdapter(checkBoxListViewAdapter);

            doneBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    ArrayList<String>    a=    checkBoxListViewAdapter.getSelectedString();

                    System.out.println("hi hi" +a);
                }
            });        


    }
    }

class CheckBoxListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private List<String> calendars = null;

    ArrayList<String> selectedString;

    public ArrayList<String> getSelectedString() {
        return selectedString;
    }

    public void setSelectedString(ArrayList<String> selectedString) {
        this.selectedString = selectedString;
    }
    static class Holder {
        CheckBox cbxSelected; 
        }
    LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public CheckBoxListViewAdapter(Activity activity, ConferenceAdapter adapter, ArrayList<String> checkBoxData) {
        this.calendars = checkBoxData;

         selectedString = new ArrayList<String>();
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return calendars.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View row, ViewGroup parent) {
Context context = null;
        Holder holder = null;
        View vi = row;
        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ec_checkbox_number, null);

            holder = new Holder();
            holder.cbxSelected = (CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (Holder)row.getTag();
            holder.cbxSelected.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        }

        holder.cbxSelected.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked) {
                    selectedString.add("k");
                }
                else {
                    // do something
                }
                //cbxZoneChecked.setChecked(CurrentContext.RatingItems.Items.contains(ratingChoosenItems.get(position)));

            }
        });


        return vi;
    }


}
```

I do know how to complete this.Any answers will be helpful

```
error is,10-23 13:18:42.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2901): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-23 13:18:42.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2901): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-23 13:18:42.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2901):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.from(LayoutInflater.java:211)
10-23 13:18:42.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2901):     at com.bambeeq.conferencecall.CheckBoxListViewAdapter.getView(EcConferenceNumber.java:113)
10-23 13:18:42.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2901):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2472)
10-23 13:18:42.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2901):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1775)
10-23 13:18:42.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2901):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:678)
10-23 13:18:42.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2901):     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:739)
10-23 13:18:42.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2901):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1628)
10-23 13:18:42.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2901):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2307)
10-23 13:18:42.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2901):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14107)
10-23 13:18:42.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2901):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4655)
10-23 13:18:42.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2901):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:948)
10-23 13:18:42.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2901):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14107)
10-23 13:18:42.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2901):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4655)
10-23 13:18:42.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2901):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
10-23 13:18:42.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2901):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14107)
10-23 13:18:42.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2901):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4655)
10-23 13:18:42.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2901):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
10-23 13:18:42.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2901):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1513)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to maintain checkboxes state which you checked. After that you have to put setonclicklistener to checkbox not setoncheckedchangedlistener and in onclick method you check that if checkbox is checked then put text in to arraylist otherwise not.

For further information checkout this [link](http://androidcocktail.blogspot.in/2012/04/adding-checkboxes-to-custom-listview-in.html).

Comment: I do not know how to maintain the checkbox state.any sample code will be helpfull

Answer (score 0):

you should to define Holder class in you Adapter

```
static class Holder {
CheckBox cbxSelected; 
}
```

Initialize it in getView()

```
Holder holder = null;
```

To read value from holder add this in getView()

```
if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ec_checkbox_number, null);

            holder = new Holder();
            holder.cbxSelected = (CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.cbxChecked);
            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (Holder)convertView.getTag();
            holder.cbxSelected.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        }
```

Also add CheckBox listener in getView:

```
holder.cbxSelected.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked) {
                    //do somethind
                }
                else {
                    // do something
                }
                //cbxZoneChecked.setChecked(CurrentContext.RatingItems.Items.contains(ratingChoosenItems.get(position)));
                CashWork.clearRatioCash();
            }
        });
```

Comment: public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
final Context context = null;
  Holder holder = null;
  View row = convertView;
  if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ec_checkbox_number, null);
    holder = new Holder();
            holder.cbxSelected = (CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (Holder)convertView.getTag();
            holder.cbxSelected.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        }

Comment: Change BaseAdapter to ArrayAdapter<YouClass>. In adapter constructor you must pass array of YouClass. In getView, you can link you current object like this: myArray[position].

Comment: Why don't you look for example? This question discussed a lot of times. For example here [lilnk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8060514/android-listview-with-check-boxes)