# Checking Checkbox When Listview Item is Selected

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, android-checkbox

So essentially I have a listview that contains a custom adapter that deals with formatting the listview. The custom view used by the adapter contains a checkbox that I want to be checked with the check locked when the listview item is selected. After much searching and various attempts at accomplishing this I have not been successful. Any ideas as to how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code for my main class:

```
public class AbWorkout extends Activity {

Button back;
ListView workoutExerciseList;
WorkoutTracker tracker;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ab_workout);


    /**
     * The database used to pull all exercises for this workout routine
     */
    final DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    final SQLiteDatabase database = db.getReadableDatabase();

    final Context context = this;

    /**
     * Get all exercises from Triceps and Chest workout and put in arraylist
     */
    workoutExerciseList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView10);
    final List<String> arrayWorkoutExercises = new ArrayList<String>();
    final ArrayAdapter<String> exListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, arrayWorkoutExercises);
    workoutExerciseList.setAdapter(exListAdapter);


            //Holds all the available exercises
    final List<WorkoutTracker> exerciseList = db.getRepetitionWorkoutRoutine(context, database, "Abs");

    /**
     * Populates the listView with each exercise for this workout routine. This includes the
     * each exercise name, the number of repetitions, the weight of the exercise, and any
     * comments included.
     */
    List<AbWorkout.RepListViewItem> repProgressList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i<exerciseList.size(); i++) {
        final int j = i;
        repProgressList.add(new AbWorkout.RepListViewItem()
        {{
                REPETITIONS = exerciseList.get(j).getReps();
                WEIGHT = exerciseList.get(j).getWeight();
                COMMENT = exerciseList.get(j).getComment();
                EXERCISE_NAME = exerciseList.get(j).getExerciseName();
            }});


    }
    final AbViewAdapter adapter = new AbViewAdapter(this, repProgressList);
    workoutExerciseList.setAdapter(adapter);


    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.CheckBox);

    workoutExerciseList.setItemChecked(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE, true);

    /*
        Upon selection of an exercise, it is highlighted and its name, date,
        and number of reps is stored in repetition progress table
    */
    workoutExerciseList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> myAdapter, View myView, int myItemInt, long mylng) {

            CheckBox check = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.CheckBox);
            //check.setChecked(true);

            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");
            //Get today's date formatted like this: dd-MM-yy
            String exDate = format.format(calendar.getTime());


            //When exercise is selected, change the color and make it unselectable.
            myAdapter.getChildAt(myItemInt).setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);
            myAdapter.getChildAt(myItemInt).setEnabled(false);
            myAdapter.getChildAt(myItemInt).setClickable(false);
            myView.setClickable(true);


            tracker = exerciseList.get(myItemInt);
            db.addNewRepProgress(new WorkoutTracker(tracker.getExerciseName(), tracker.getReps(), tracker.getWeight(), tracker.getComment(), exDate), context, database);
            Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "Workout Progress was successfully saved.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });


    back = (Button)findViewById(R.id.back);
    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_ab_workout, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


public class RepListViewItem
{
    public int REPETITIONS;
    public double WEIGHT;
    public String COMMENT;
    public String EXERCISE_NAME;
    public String DATE;
}
}
```

And here is the code for my adapter class:

```
public class AbViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{

LayoutInflater inflater;
List<AbWorkout.RepListViewItem> items;
int pos = 0;

public AbViewAdapter(Activity context, List<AbWorkout.RepListViewItem> items) {
    super();

    this.items = items;
    this.inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    AbWorkout.RepListViewItem item = items.get(position);
    View vi=convertView;

    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rep_item_row, null);


    TextView exerciseName = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.FullProgress);
    TextView exerciseReps = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.Time);
    TextView exerciseComment = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.Comment);
    TextView exerciseWeight = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.Distance);
    CheckBox check = (CheckBox)vi.findViewById(R.id.CheckBox);

    exerciseName.setText(item.EXERCISE_NAME);
    exerciseReps.setText(String.valueOf(item.REPETITIONS));
    exerciseComment.setText(item.COMMENT);
    exerciseWeight.setText(String.valueOf(item.WEIGHT));

    pos = position;

    return vi;
}
}
```

Comment: you want change your list view based on item selection?

Comment: Next to each listview item there's a checkbox. Whenever the listview item is selected (not when the checkbox is selected), I want the checkbox to be checked.

Comment: use vi.setOnClickListener in adapter view it prevents list view to process item click listener then you can put your highlight and etc in onClick method inside adapter

Answer (score 0):

In your `AbViewAdapter.getView()`, add an `OnClickListener`

Then, in the `OnClickListener`, toggle the checkbox state with:
`check.setChecked(!isChecked())`

Full answer here: [Android listview with check boxes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8060514/android-listview-with-check-boxes/8060732#8060732)

Full tutorial here: http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-checkbox-example.html

Comment: This is similar to what I need, but I am merely using the checkbox as a cosmetic thing. The checkbox is not meant to be selected, but rather it is checked when its corresponding listview item is selected. Checking the checkbox is not meant to do anything.

Comment: @Deus Should the user be able to select multiple checkboxes, or do you want single-mode, like radio-buttons?

Comment: Well the user won't be able to select any checkboxes in theory. The checkboxes are just there to reinforce that they have selected that listview item. But multiple checkboxes can be selected automatically if the user selects multiple listview items.

Answer (score 0):

because when you scroll your listview, the item in A will be destroyed. When scroll up, the item in A will be re-created.

[image]

So the CheckBox is re-create too, you need to store item when to restore this current state when scroll up. Let see [ViewHolder](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html)