# How to set ArrayList with isChecked in CheckBox android

Tags: java, android, checkbox

How to set data with checkbox when user clicks submit? I want to get all data within `isChecked()`

And I try this code which doesn't work.

myadapter

```
viewHoder.cx_select_invite.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            Log.d("ChatGroupInviteAdap", "onClick position: " + position);
            Log.d("ChatGroupInviteAdap", "onClick getFirstname: " + chatFriendsListModels.get(position).getFirstname());
            id = chatFriendsListModels.get(position).getId();
            ChatGroupInviteFragment.dataMember.add(id);
        }

        if (!isChecked) {
            id = chatFriendsListModels.get(position).getId();
            ChatGroupInviteFragment.dataMember.remove(id);
        }

    }
});
```

myFragment

user clicks submit when user checks finish

```
tx_submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d(TAG, "OnClick: " + ChatGroupInviteFragment.dataMember.size());

        for (int i=0;i<ChatGroupInviteFragment.dataMember.size();i++){
            Log.d(TAG, "OnClick2 : " + ChatGroupInviteFragment.dataMember.get(i));
        }
    }
});
```

I get error when user unChecked

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                            Process: xxx.xx.x, PID: 20496
>                                                                            java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 36, size is 3

```
36 is id unChecked

and 3 = size isChecked
```

How to set it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android listview with check boxes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8060514/android-listview-with-check-boxes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add one boolean parameter `isChecked` to your model class 
and then do like this

```
    viewHoder.cx_select_invite.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                chatFriendsListModels.isChecked(isChecked);

            }
        });
```

and then on your final submit button do like this

```
tx_submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        for (int i=0;i<chatFriendsListModels.size();i++){
            if(chatFriendsListModels.isChecked()==true)
           String id = chatFriendsListModels.get(i).getId();
            // you do what you want with id here
        }


    }
});
```

Comment: wecome , here is my android tutorial with Kotlin https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCC_cuZHf2M9HrHo5OxOU3zA

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you are using two different `List` in the `for` loop.

```
 for (int i=0;i<ChatGroupInviteFragment.getListFriend.size();i++){
                    Log.d(TAG, "OnClick2 : " + ChatGroupInviteFragment.dataMember.get(i))            
 }
```

Here you are iterating the `ChatGroupInviteFragment.getListFriend` list which size seems to be **36**. while you are getting the data from `ChatGroupInviteFragment.dataMember` whose size seems to be **3** hence `ArrayOutOfBoundException`.

You should change to :

```
for (int i=0;i<ChatGroupInviteFragment.dataMember.size() - 1;i++)
 {
  Log.d(TAG, "OnClick2 : " + ChatGroupInviteFragment.dataMember.get(i))            
 }
```

Comment: check now . changed the iteration counter

Comment: still error, this problem is when if user checked size =3 and when user unchecked position > 3  it's error

Comment: are u sure u copied the 2nd one ? . this cant through an exception.

Answer (score 0):

getView():

```
viewHoder.cx_select_invite.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {


                int position=  viewHolder.checkbox.getTag(); //Try to get position this way

                id = chatFriendsListModels.get(position).getId();
                ChatGroupInviteFragment.dataMember.add(id);
            }
            if (!isChecked) {
                id = chatFriendsListModels.get(position).getId();
                ChatGroupInviteFragment.dataMember.remove(id);
            }

        }
    });

    viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(position);
```

Comment: sorry  int position   ,Have a try

Comment: in line   `int position=  viewHolder.checkbox.getTag(); ` viewHolder is accessed from within inner class